# JS not working properly with AngularJS ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

for an AngularJS SPA project I'm using `ngRoute` and also Bootstrap's Carousel template. However, I've encountered a problem where some functionality stopped working as soon as I used `ng-view` instead of just putting all of the main body in the main `index.html` file.

I have created the most bare-bones Plunker I could [demonstrating the bug here](https://plnkr.co/edit/5bmyvrqGoMXzOka6EfOh?p=preview).

Basically, there is a carousel containing 4 parts and the next/prev arrows do not work properly. However, I left at the bottom narrow indicators letting you move freely between the parts. They work properly. Also, the sequence continues as it should (i.e changes by itself) when left untouched.

Notice that if I swap `carousel.html` with the `ng-view` tag, it works fine.

I've just begun learning to use AngularJS and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Instead of using bootstrap js library you need to replace it with angular ui bootstrap. 
Check it out here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

Comment: There is no bug, you are simply changing the route with `href="#myCarousel"`, so it goes to `/#/myCarousel`. It doesn't have such route listed with `.when`, so it goes to `.otherwise` and you are always being redirected to `/home`. Simply use `ui.bootstrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue using BootstrapJs inside AngularJS as an external library, you have to use the bootstrap methods for [bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#methods): `.carousel('prev')` and `.carousel('next')` then create relative `$scope` functions and link it to the prev and next button with `ng-click`.

This is your [plunker edited](https://plnkr.co/edit/7AHyLMJx6DmmHGTPuJmG?p=preview).

But a best and cleaner solution would be to use ui-bootstrap library for AngularJS and Bootstrap.  [This is a fork for Bootstrap 4](https://github.com/Morgul/ui-bootstrap4)

Comment: While this is correct _follow the advise to use the angular ui bootstrap_.  Using the standard jQuery bootstrap is a _recipe for headaches_.

Comment: Sure. Use the angular ui bootstrap is the best solution. With the standard library you are doing a double job, which has already been done

Comment: Does this mean most of the useful components (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/alerts/) are irrelevant?

Comment: @TomDawn - check out angular ui bootstrap.  It's very full featured.  And NO - that's a different thing - that's a simple CSS _class_ - you an absolutely use that.  We're referring to the javascript elements of bootstrap, not the CSS.

Comment: @TomDawn the angular ui bootstrap has all the bootstrap JavaScript Components translated in a more accurate angular way: directives. So you can have a better control about every bootstrap feature with all the benefits of angular framework.